# Приличный / Воспитанный / Культурный / Интеллигентный

Tags: семантика, общие-вопросы

Одного слова достаточно, чтобы выразить свою симпатию даже к малознакомому человеку. Есть несколько синонимов. Мне интересно уловить разницу в значениях этих слов.

Какими качествами должен обладать человек, чтобы вы дали ему такую характеристику? Какого человека вы так никогда не назовете?

1. Приличный
2. Воспитанный
3. Культурный
4. Интеллигентный

---

Уточню вопрос. Я имею в виду назвать человека в третьем лице. И, заодно, вы можете так сказать о себе лично?

---

Comment: Да ведь это всё понятно (что речь вообще не о собеседнике). Мы "откусываем" от вашего вопроса какие-то мелочи, потому что он слишком обширный (об одном только "интеллигенте" легко можно холивар развести на 100 страниц). 

К тому же вопрос больше "философский", не совсем по теме "русский язык". Дать самому себе оценку - это уже из какой-то "духовной" области (а делать это прилюдно - вообще лютеранство какое-то, в стиле отца Фёдора).

------------

Я бы ограничил как-то. Например, взял одно из четырёх слов и привёл пару противоречивых значений...

Comment: Вопрос, может, и философский, но очень даже по теме "русский язык". Многие употребляют эти слова к месту и не к месту, и каждый имеет в виду что-то своё. Произнося их, Вы уверены, что Вас достаточно понимают? Я прошу участников форума объяснить, что лично они подразумевают под этими словами.

Comment: Вопрос пограничный. Вот это - что "лично каждый подразумевает" - не предмет лингвистики (и вообще не предмет науки). А вот "к месту или не к месту" - вполне можно отнести к вопросам нормы. Приведите примеры неуместного, на ваш взгляд, употребления обсуждаемых слов. Я просто не могу вспомнить, когда слышал их в живой речи.

Comment: На мой взгляд, фразы типа "интеллигентные/культурные люди так не поступают" неуместны почти всегда. Потому что напрашивается вопрос: "а как они обычно поступают?".

Comment: Здесь вы не правы. Суть "культурности" в очень значительной части состоит именно в ограничениях: это, начиная с Заповедей, наборы правил, чаще всего начинающихся с НЕ.

Интеллигентность - совсем другая статья, в указанном вами контексте мне не встречалась ("интеллигентные люди так не поступают" звучит для меня непривычно).

Answer (score 2):

Никакого человека, пожалуй, так я не назову. Мне просто трудно представить такую ситуацию. Разве что в отрицательном смысле: "Семён Семёныч, ну вы же культурный человек, ну зачем же вы окурок об стену тушите?"

---

В разговоре с кем-то я тоже не люблю давать оценки третьим лицам (особенно положительные :-)). Во мне может сложиться внутренняя убеждённость в высокой культуре какого-то человека. Я бы определил этого человека примерно так: он не будет бросать мусор на пол (как в прямом, так и в переносном смысле), даже если в этот момент его никто не видит.

Comment: Называя Семёна Семёныча культурным человеком, что Вы имеете в виду? То, что он тушит окурок о стену, не заставляет Вас перестать считать его культурным?
Мне странно читать, что Вы не любите давать положительные оценки (и вообще оценки) третьим лицам. Как Вам это удается?

Comment: @yupaz, да я же шучу, иронизирую над собой (там даже специально смайлик подрисован). А если серьёзно, в любой книжке по психологическому ликбезу рекомендуют оценивать не человека, а поступки: "Семён Семёныч, вы же культурный человек, почему так некультурно **поступаете**?" Я с этой рекомендацией согласен. Но опять же: причём тут русский язык?

Answer (score 2):

И значения далеко не синонимичны, и называть человека в глаза я так не стану. За глаза могу сказать "Он - человек культурный или интеллигентный". "Воспитанный" - уже под вопросом, "приличный" - никогда. Разве что "порядочный".

Вообще в этом ряду самое интересное слово "интеллигентный". Оно не имеет сколько-нибудь содержательного формального определения. Несводимость этого понятия к простейшим давно подмечено, если не ошибаюсь, у Солоухина есть эссе на эту тему. Там есть такая мысль, что со времен Достоевского противопоставление интеллигентности ни быдлу, ни бескультурью, ни чему ещё не является исчерпывающим для понимания сути явления. Более того, слово это непереводимо на другие языки. Известны даже попытки составителей словарей характеризовать это понятие как чисто русское...
Какие уж тут "приличия".... Окончательно добивает все попытки разобраться выражение "интеллигентный хам", некогда весьма популярное.

Answer (score 1):

Насчет "приличный" — забавно. То есть, предполагается, что есть неприличные люди?))) Мне кажется, это не слишком подходящий эпитет.
Опять же, культурный и интеллигентный — тоже разные вещи. Как мне кажется, интеллигентность — это врожденное качество, а культура — уже приобретенное.

Comment: Насчет интеллигентности как врожденного качества совершенно не согласен. В семье интеллигентов может родиться и вырасти откровенный хам, жлоб и невежа, а из простой рабочей семьи может выйти утонченный интеллигент

Comment: Первые два слова в моем списке больше для затравки. Пожалуй, они самые простые для объяснения, (по крайней мере, для меня).

@Fuchoin Kazuki, так как же определить культурного / интеллигентного человека? Возможно ли понять, врожденная ли у него интеллигентность или приобретенная культурность? Как Вы считаете, существует ли генетическая предрасположенность к интеллигентности?

Comment: Виктор, я сказала не "наследственное", а "врожденное". Почувствуйте разницу)))))  
Насчет генетической ничего не скажу. Возможно, что-то существует, но, как было выше сказано, известно множество случаев, когда в семье потомственных интеллигентов рождались настоящие выродки, и наоборот.  
Хотя, с другой стороны, не даром есть такое понятие как "порода".

Answer (score 1):

Воспитанный-невоспитанный я бы употребила скорее по отношению к детям, чем взрослым. 
Приличный-культурный-интеллигентный - примерно одинаковые по смыслу, если речь идет о семье.
О конкретном человеке можно говорить, оценивая его поведение в конкретной ситуации. Например, ходила я на сальсу, где тренером был кубинец. Он не стеснялся заходить в женскую раздевалку, поэтому он невоспитанный (хотя в целом он классный - позитивный и непосредственный).

Answer (score 1):

Приличный - это тот кто соблюдает приличия, свойственные данному месту и социуму. То есть не явится в оперу в джинсах и футболке, а в турпоход в смокинге и галстуке-бабочке. Не будет при дамах рассказывать пошлый анекдот, и фикать, услышав такой анекдот в мужской компании.

Воспитанный - это тот, кто знает и соблюдает правила этикета.

Культурный - живущий по обычаям и модели поведения социума среди которого проживает.

Интеллигентный ... Это вообще чисто русское понятие. Не знаю насколько правда, но читал, что в английском есть слово [интелегэйшэн], означающее любого представителя профессии не требующей физического труда (в том числе: продавец, вахтёр) и заимствованное с русского [интелегенциа], с понятием схожим с нашим.
Интеллигент, в моём понимании - это человек имеющий достаточно знаний и умений для рефлексии. Однако при этом у интеллигента нет достаточной власти и умения управлять, чтобы выводы из своих размышлений воплощать в жизнь. Интеллигентным человек может быть до и после того как получил власть, но не во время. Интеллигенет - это тот, кто думает обо всех, но отвечает, только за себя.